# jQuery/Javascript - finding a string from an unordered list is in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to compare text in an unordered list to an array that I created by grabbing contents in a string then parsing it.  I cannot seem to get the comparison part of my jQuery code to work where I check to see if the string lives within the array.  Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<span id="Subjects">Commercial Law & Contracts, Immigration Law, International Law & Trade, Products Liability</span>
<ul id="SubjectList">
  <li>Administrative Law</li>
  <li>Agriculture Updates</li>
  <li>Alternative Dispute Resolution</li>
  <li>Antitrust & Trade Regulation</li>
  <li>Commercial Law & Contracts</li>
  <li>Immigration Law</li>
  <li>International Law & Trade</li>
  <li>Products Liability</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery Code

```
var subject_passed = $('#Subjects').text();
var subjectArray = new Array();
subjectArray = subject_passed.split(',');   

$('#SubjectList li').each(function(){  
    if ($.inArray($(this).text(), subjectArray) != -1) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

Comment: The strings in your array have spaces, you may want to trim those away.

Comment: Or `var subjectArray=$('#Subjects').text().split(', ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
var subject_passed = $('#Subjects').text();
//var subjectArray = new Array(); //not really needed as split returns new a array
var subjectArray = subject_passed.split(', '); //add a space to split

$('#SubjectList li').each(function(){  
   if ($.inArray($(this).text(), subjectArray) !== -1) { //better to use !== for comparison
     alert('hello');
   }
});
```

Comment: Oh snap.  Thanks!  That's exactly what I needed to get it to work.  I hate it when I'm so close yet so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$.trim()` to remove the outer whitespace from the text values after the split and during the comparison:

```
var subject_passed = $('#Subjects').text();
var subjectArray = subject_passed.split(','); 
$.each(subjectArray, function(i, el){
    subjectArray[i] = $.trim(el);
});

$('#SubjectList li').each(function(){  
    if ($.inArray($.trim($(this).text()), subjectArray) != -1) {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    }
});​
```

### [See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8qr7/)

Comment: Definitely.  I did use trim in my code in the end.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add a space after the comma in the following line...

```
subjectArray = subject_passed.split(', ');
```